# Getting Null pointer exception on overriding assistedServiceService in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

After overriding OOB assistedServiceService I am getting NPE in OOB class `DefaultAssistedServiceFacade.java`  for line `assistedServiceService.getAsmSession()`

To override service I have followed below steps.

1- Declared bean in customextension-core-spring.xml file as below

```
<alias name="defaultcustomAssistedServiceService" alias="assistedServiceService"/>
<bean id="defaultcustomAssistedServiceService" class="com.custom.core.services.impl.DefaultCustomAssistedServiceService" parent ="defaultAssistedServiceService"><br>        <property name="flexibleSearchService" ref="flexibleSearchService"/>
</bean>
```

2- Created a custom class overriding OOB `defaultCustomAssistedServiceService`  class

```
public class DefaultCustomAssistedServiceService extends DefaultAssistedServiceService implements CustomAssistedServiceService {
private FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService;

@Override
public CartModel getCartByCode(final String cartCode) {
}

public FlexibleSearchService getFlexibleSearchService() {
    return flexibleSearchService;
}

public void setFlexibleSearchService(FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService) {
    this.flexibleSearchService = flexibleSearchService;
}
```

Since Object of assistedServiceService is already been used in other OOB classes, So wherever its been called it is giving NPE. Am I missing something in service overriding?

Please note OOB assistedServiceService is defined in OOB extension 'assistedServiceService' in file assistedserviceservices-spring.xml as

```
 <alias name="defaultAssistedServiceService" alias="assistedServiceService"/>
<bean id="defaultAssistedServiceService" class="de.hybris.platform.assistedserviceservices.impl.DefaultAssistedServiceService">
    <property name="modelService" ref="modelService"/>
    <property name="userService" ref="userService"/>
    <property name="baseSiteService" ref="baseSiteService"/>
    <property name="cartService" ref="cartService"/>
    <property name="sessionService" ref="sessionService"/>
    <property name="flexibleSearchService" ref="flexibleSearchService"/>
    <property name="pagedFlexibleSearchService" ref="pagedFlexibleSearchService"/>
    <property name="commerceCartService" ref="commerceCartService"/>
    <property name="customerAccountService" ref="customerAccountService"/>
    <property name="commonI18NService" ref="commonI18NService"/>
    <property name="timeService" ref="timeService"/>
</bean>
```

Below is stacktrace which I am getting

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Error while processing internal filterchain. Exception occurred at chain position: 11 of 17. Current filter: 'FilterChainProxy[Filter Chains: [[ Ant [pattern='/_ui/**'], []], [ Ant [pattern='/checkout/**'], [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@63e1e0e7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6b94c056, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@21cc977c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@473f7e49, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2b355891, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@666ebbd1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@235ca717, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1fad4803, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1edd7ab7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@dfefa8e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4bdc9039, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3ec43411, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4b39f9bc]], [ com.custom.equipment.security.ExcludeUrlRequestMatcher@7c8d71a8, [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@1b535de5, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@13338461, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@10e5e5df, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@772c65a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2b355891, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6cf0f24, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@9d09310, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@36a444e8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@27750470, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@59bd9995, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5478c9a1, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@406f54c2, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4fb68e3b]], [ org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RegexRequestMatcher@76ae7043, [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@557fbc59, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5d8731bd, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7d6c98eb, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7845d36d, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@50703548, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@349efc22, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2d2c919a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7ba4f1e9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2a2f51a0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6993c72b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@207a3bc2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7c0dbd9d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2cff51ed]]]]'!; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.hybris.platform.assistedservicefacades.impl.DefaultAssistedServiceFacade.getAsmSession(DefaultAssistedServiceFacade.java:725)
at de.hybris.platform.assistedservicefacades.impl.DefaultAssistedServiceFacade.isAssistedServiceModeLaunched(DefaultAssistedServiceFacade.java:140)
at com.custom.asm.aspect.ChannelDecisionAspect.isAssistedServiceMode(ChannelDecisionAspect.java:87)
at com.custom.asm.aspect.ChannelDecisionAspect.decideAround(ChannelDecisionAspect.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:616)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59a46d4f.decide()
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.FileUploadFilter.doFilterInternal(FileUploadFilter.java:51)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.UrlEncoderFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlEncoderFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.StorefrontFilter.doFilterInternal(StorefrontFilter.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerFilter.java:71)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:128)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:99)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:44)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.session.HybrisSpringSessionFilter.doFilter(HybrisSpringSessionFilter.java:69)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.processStandardFilterChain(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:206)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.UrlPathFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlPathFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:358)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Mar 02, 2022 11:02:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Error while processing internal filterchain. Exception occurred at chain position: 11 of 17. Current filter: 'FilterChainProxy[Filter Chains: [[ Ant [pattern='/_ui/**'], []], [ Ant [pattern='/checkout/**'], [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@63e1e0e7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@6b94c056, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@21cc977c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@473f7e49, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2b355891, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@666ebbd1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@235ca717, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1fad4803, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1edd7ab7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@dfefa8e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4bdc9039, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3ec43411, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4b39f9bc]], [ com.custom.equipment.security.ExcludeUrlRequestMatcher@7c8d71a8, [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@1b535de5, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@13338461, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@10e5e5df, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@772c65a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2b355891, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6cf0f24, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@9d09310, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@36a444e8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@27750470, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@59bd9995, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5478c9a1, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@406f54c2, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4fb68e3b]], [ org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RegexRequestMatcher@76ae7043, [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@557fbc59, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@5d8731bd, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7d6c98eb, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7845d36d, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@50703548, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@349efc22, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2d2c919a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7ba4f1e9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2a2f51a0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6993c72b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@207a3bc2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7c0dbd9d, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2cff51ed]]]]'!; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.hybris.platform.assistedservicefacades.impl.DefaultAssistedServiceFacade.getAsmSession(DefaultAssistedServiceFacade.java:725)
at de.hybris.platform.assistedservicefacades.impl.DefaultAssistedServiceFacade.isAssistedServiceModeLaunched(DefaultAssistedServiceFacade.java:140)
at com.custom.asm.aspect.ChannelDecisionAspect.isAssistedServiceMode(ChannelDecisionAspect.java:87)
at com.custom.asm.aspect.ChannelDecisionAspect.decideAround(ChannelDecisionAspect.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:616)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59a46d4f.decide()
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.FileUploadFilter.doFilterInternal(FileUploadFilter.java:51)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.UrlEncoderFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlEncoderFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.StorefrontFilter.doFilterInternal(StorefrontFilter.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerFilter.java:71)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:128)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:99)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:44)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.session.HybrisSpringSessionFilter.doFilter(HybrisSpringSessionFilter.java:69)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:297)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.processStandardFilterChain(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:206)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.UrlPathFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlPathFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.custom.equipment.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:358)
at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Answer (score 1):

fixed the error by calling super method in facade, where I was setting the object of service.

```
public void setAssistedServiceService(CustomAssistedServiceService assistedServiceService) {
    super.setAssistedServiceService(assistedServiceService);
    this.assistedServiceService = assistedServiceService;
}
```